# Запуск apache под другим пользователем

Tags: ubuntu, apache, laravel

Здравствуйте. Проблема вот в чем, для папки с проектом я установил права 777
`chmod -R 777 /site` и еще так `chmod -R 777 /site/*`
Через файловый менеджер показывает, что владелец `user`, а apache запускается под `www-data`, возникает ситуация что не отображаются ошибки и не пишутся логи. Можно ли запускать apache под рутом или другим пользователем, либо изменить права на каталог, чтобы все было нормально?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

наиболее логично: сделать владельцем файлов/каталогов пользователя `www-data` и запретить изменение файлов/каталогов другим пользователям.

примерно так:

```
$ sudo chown -R www-data /site
$ sudo chmod -R go-w /site
```

Comment: Спасибо. Все отлично заработало)